# Comparing two slots of lecture of two different timetable

Tags: timetable

I am crating a java based timetable generation app. It is an android application. The inputs from the user are subject name and professor name. Both values are stored in a 2D array tt1[][] . The same i have done for time table 2 and stored inputs in array tt2[][]. Now i want to create two time tables using this value. Timetable will be generated and displayed in gridview..First timetable will b generated that is not an issue, but for timetable 2  I want to compare each slot of timetable 1 with timetable 2. I m thinking of using if-else statement but its way too lengthy. Can you suggest something better? [I have a created timetable 1 and the sample code is for timetable 2. For each slot of a day I am using if else statement and it is getting too length as there can be 10 slots in a single day. To generate for 6 days it will become 6×10 if-else statements](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vJRip.jpg)

Comment: First try out what you think is lengthy then share here if we can help to improve. Else there's another site called https://codereview.stackexchange.com/ you can post your length code there too to get it improved.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. I have edited my question can you please take a look at it?

Comment: It's better to post code instead of image.
I think your approach is good just one thing you'll need to use == instead of = to compare inside the if condition rest you can try running your code and let the error be posted in the question

Comment: Okay..but cant something else be used instead of if-else statement

Comment: Simply use for loop you'll need two for loop to loop inside one array

Comment: I am using two for loops but slot 1 of each day is assigned same value. I tried putting it other way then same subjects are assigned to a single day.

Comment: Please post your updated code